# Unable to access ports on Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, windows-firewall

I created a Windows VM on Azure, I was able to access it via RDP. I hosted a site on IIS and linked it to a port(8010), accessed it through `localhost:8010`. Then I made an **Inbound filter rule**  on the firewall to access it via Pubic IP, I wasn't able to access. I changed the port to 8015, also didn't work.
this is the first time I use Azure services, I don't know what is the issue here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCbB3.png)

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to amend the Network Security Group in Azure that is attached to the VM to allow inbound traffic on the required port.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, go to the Azure Portal, click the VM and click the "Networking" tab. On the right, click "Add inbound port rule".

Configure it as follow's:

- Source: Any (or change if needed of course)
- Source Port: *
- Destination: IP Address
- Destination port range: your port
- Protocol: TCP
- Action: allow

You don't need to create an outbound port rule as NSG's are stateful.